# Include match index in Regex replacement string

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a situation where I need to strip out HTML code from some text. However, some of the input text includes lists, and I want to retain the numbering in that case.

If I do

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, "<li>", vbNewLine & "1. ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Then after stripping out the other HTML tags, I end up with:

```
1. List item one
1. List item two
1. List item three
```

Is there a way to get the index of the match during replacement?

so for example:

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, "<li>", vbNewLine & replacementIndex + 1 & " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Then after stripping out the other HTML tags, I would get:

```
1. List item one
2. List item two
3. List item three
```

Is this possible??

Note: This is inside a function, so that each list is handled separately, and unordered lists get bullets (*) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it - first, find each ordered list:

```
Dim result As String = rawText
Dim orderedLists As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(rawText, "<ol>.*?</ol>", RegexOptions.Singleline)

For Each ol As Match In orderedLists
    result = Replace(result, ol.Value, EncodeOrderedList(ol.Value))
Next
```

And the function to convert each one:

```
Private Function EncodeOrderedList(ByVal rawText As String) As String
    Dim result As String = rawText
    result = Regex.Replace(result, "<ol>\s*<li>", "1. ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    result = Regex.Replace(result, "</li>\s*</ol>", vbNewLine & vbNewLine, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim bullets As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(rawText, "</li>\s*<li>")
    Dim i As Integer = 2
    For Each li As Match In bullets
        result = Replace(result, li.Value, vbNewLine & i & ". ", 1, 1)
        i += 1
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

I haven't tested it on nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good starting point. `@"(\<ul\>)((.|\n)*?)(\<\/ul\>)"` this will match everything in between the  tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but something like the following.  Only change one at a time.  This may be slow for large data sets.

```
int lineNbr = 1;
string newResult = result.Replace("(?i)<li>", vbNewLine & (lineNbr++).ToString() & '. ', 1);
while (newResult != result)
{
   result = newResult;
   newResult = result.Replace("(?i)<li>", vbNewLine & (lineNbr++).ToString() & '. ', 1);
}
```